# Managing buttons on default "share" iOS dialog

Tags: ios, iphone, sharing

In my iPhone application, I need to implement the "tell friends about this app" feature, which is supposed to share an app url. In order to do that, I decided to use the standard iOS "share" dialog.

The problem I have is that (at least) on iOS 7, in addition to "email" and "sms" buttons, I see "copy", "save image" and "print" buttons as well. These buttons make no sense for this feature, I would like to hide them.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using **UIActivityViewController** class:

**UIActivityViewController** has a property named **excludedActivityTypes** that is of type **NSArray**. You set this before presenting the controller.

Assuming an instance of **UIActivityViewController** named **activityVC** -

```
    // create an NSArray of exclusions for copy, save image and print
    NSArray *excludedTypes = @[UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypePrint];
    // assign array of exclusions to excludedActivityTypes property of UIActivityController
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludedTypes;
```

Apples [UIActivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011974-CH1-SW13) Class Reference contains a list of *Built-in Activity Types* that are defined as string constants that may be used.

Answer (score 1):

Before you present the viewController, tell it what not to show:

```
av.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
```